# I need to set up a sftp server, that could use different keys, and use different directories for the same login, depending on the ip used

Tags: virtualization, sftp, hosts, proftpd

I got a problem, that I cannot solve myself. I tried to google it, but no satiscactory solution that i could find.
I have a server that is available with let's say 3 different IP addresses (**A**,**B**,**C**), and a user login lets say "**user**".
I need to setup an sftp server that:
when connected with IP A, the SFTP server will announce itself with Key A, when connected with B, announces itself with key B, and so on.
But that is not the end, of the problem, I want to set it up, so when a client tries to connect to "user" with IP A, it would use directory A for accessing user files, when connected with IP B it would use direcotry B, and when connected with IP C, then it would use directory C.
I thought of proftpd with sftp mod on, but I got stuck on how to configure directories, that would be accessed with login "user".
for eg. 
if client tries to access file:
**user@A:file.dat**
real pathname would be **directoryA/file.dat**
if client tries to access:
**user@B:file.dat**
the real pathname would be **directoryB/file.dat**
and so on...
Now the question is, how to set it up?

Comment: multiple instances of sshd bound to the three ips would probably do this.  If you are using keys to connect, I notice you can specify environment variables within authorized_keys, and may be able to affect the home directory of the connecting user.

Comment: yes, that I considered,but I will have more than 3 ips, and unfortunately I will have to configure more and more with time. Running multiple instances of ssh would be kind of problematic... And yes, I will have a key authorization...

Comment: Do they have to use the same private key with all ip addresses? user@A, user@B, user@C it should be the same private key?

Answer (score 1):

Your `proftpd.conf` for this would, I think, look something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_sftp.c>
  # Virtual host configuration for server A
  <VirtualHost a.a.a.a>
    Port 22
    SFTPEngine on
    SFTPHostKey /path/to/key/A

    # Restrict members of group A to this directory
    DefaultRoot /path/to/directoryA groupA
  </VirtualHost>

  # Virtual host configuration for server B
  <VirtualHost b.b.b.b>
    Port 22
    SFTPEngine on
    SFTPHostKey /path/to/key/B

    # Restrict members of group A to this directory
    DefaultRoot /path/to/directoryB groupB
  </VirtualHost>

  # Virtual host configuration for server C
  <VirtualHost c.c.c.c>
    Port 22
    SFTPEngine on
    SFTPHostKey /path/to/key/C

    # Restrict members of group C to this directory
    DefaultRoot /path/to/directoryC groupC
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The key part of making the above work is to use the optional *group parameter* of the `DefaultRoot` directive (for more info, I recommend the [Chroot howto](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Chroot.html)).

The user name "user" would be configured slightly different for each of your virtual hosts.  For server A, "user" would be a member of group A.  For server B, "user" would be a member of group B.  And for server C, "user" is a member of group C.  If you did not want to use chroot restrictions for any reason, you could use the `DefaultChdir` directive instead; this simply places the authenticated client at the requested directory at the start of their session, once they've authenticated.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You could try Sysax Server. It is not free but gets the job done.